# Read mixed language txt file in TCL

Tags: character-encoding, tcl

I need to read a text file that contains mixed languages (German & Arabic) in a TCL script. When I open the file with utf-8 encoding, only German letters are recognized correctly.

```
set My_Sheet [open $ref_book r]
fconfigure $My_Sheet -encoding utf-8
```

Does anyone konw what the correct encoding that I can use to open the file.

P.S: when I type

```
encoding names
```

I can see the following encodings are available:

```
cp860 cp861 cp862 cp863 tis-620 cp864 cp865 cp866 gb12345 gb2312-raw 

cp949 cp950 cp869 dingbats ksc5601 macCentEuro cp874 macUkraine 

jis0201 gb2312 euc-cn euc-jp macThai iso8859-10 jis0208 iso2022-jp macIceland 

iso2022 iso8859-13 jis0212 iso8859-14 iso8859-15 cp737 iso8859-16 big5 euc-kr 

macRomania macTurkish gb1988 iso2022-kr macGreek ascii cp437 macRoman 

iso8859-1 iso8859-2 iso8859-3 macCroatian koi8-r iso8859-4 ebcdic iso8859-5 

cp1250 macCyrillic iso8859-6 cp1251 macDingbats koi8-u iso8859-7 cp1252 

iso8859-8 cp1253 iso8859-9 cp1254 cp1255 cp850 cp1256 cp932 identity cp1257 cp852 

macJapan cp1258 shiftjis utf-8 cp855 cp936 symbol cp775 unicode cp857
```

Comment: First you need to figure out what encoding(s) the text in the file uses, if it's not utf-8 for everything. If it is all utf-8, are the characters that aren't being handled outside of the BMP? Can whatever you're using to look at the file render arabic text correctly?

Comment: You can change the encoding you're using for the file at any time you want, or you can open the file in binary mode and do the decoding manually with `encoding convertfrom`. But without knowing the encoding actually used for the Arabic, it's hard to advise. (It might be `iso8859-6`.) ***Mixed encoding text is difficult to work with in general.***

Comment: The problem was at my side .. after I opened the file with (fconfigure ... -encoding utf-8), I read further the content after converting it again to utf-8 (set csvContent [encoding convertto utf-8 [read $MySheet]]) .. so I was converting to utf-8 twice.